# Race Track in OpenGL (Catmull-Rom)?

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, 3d, splines

I'm making a simple 3D racing game for my project. I'm wondering about using the Catmull-Rom splines.

I've set the texture of it. I've also created a functional which takes 4 points and t (the distance between the 2 nearest control points). I've initialized the spline to take 4 CVector3f's, but now i don't know what to do, i.e. how to render it, how to create curves...

Comment: What type of OpenGL do you use?Fixed or programmable?Anyway,you should render lines for your spline geometry

Comment: For efficient subdivision and rendering, the [de Casteljau algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau's_algorithm) exploits the form of the [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Not always the best choice of representation for modelling, but usually the best choice for evaluation.

Comment: Michael, how would i check if OpenGL is fixed or programmable? All i know is that i'm using version 2.3.

Comment: Hi Brett, do you know how I would implement this into code? It's just the rendering i'm having difficulty conjuring up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said,just render your splines as line segments.For fixed pipeline,if you made more research effort, you would find [this](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://extras.springer.com/2012/978-1-4471-2340-8/Chapter7/Code/CatmullRom.cpp&ei=UyxYUqaSLMOE4ATI2YHwBA&usg=AFQjCNE9Qre18VzEnxUgC0hs9OxIwNcVig&sig2=FDPDZYlc1UPlH8srUe--Xg).If you plan to use modern OpenGL just pack all the segment start-end points into buffer and draw lines.

Comment: I searched CatMull-Rom splines OpenGL and i never came across that... I was searching all day! But thanks